# What part of speech is "(noun) the (noun)"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, parts-of-speech

What part of speech is the part boldfaced in these sentences?

- **Chell the protagonist of Portal** is a woman.
- **Ludwig Wittgenstein the Austrian-British philosopher** worked primarily in logic.
- **Tim Berners-Lee the inventor of the World Wide Web** said "more you enter, the more you become locked in".

Comment: Each of the bolded phrases consists of several words. Each of those words is a certain part of speech. (*Chell* and *Portal* are (proper) nouns, *the* is an article, *of* is a preposition, *protagonist* is a noun, and so on.) The phrase as a whole is not a part of speech. It is a phrase. More precisely, each of the phrases is a noun phrase, and each of them contains another, parenthetical, phrase. Which should be set off by commas. All three examples are not properly punctuated.

Comment: What is wrong with *noun phrase*? http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/noun%2Bphrase

Comment: @KitFox This may be GR, but there's nothing unreal at all about it. :)

Comment: @Kris The unreal part is that the bolded part is not a part of speech, rather it is several.  That makes the question ambiguous and vague.

Comment: In contemporary linguistics, the term *part of speech* has generally been discarded in favor of the label *word class* or *syntactic category*. The answer to this question is *noun phrase*.

Comment: @KitFox See Edwin Ashworth below. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110352/what-part-of-speech-is-noun-the-noun?noredirect=1#comment223860_110353

Answer (score 1):

Phrases don't really have parts of speech - single words do - but these are all **noun phrases** formed by the **apposition** of two smaller noun phrases.

Comment: Why can't we just say thay're *noun phrases*, which they are?

Comment: It would then be preferable to clarify that the definition of POS you are using is not the narrower one (eg **MW**:)

: a traditional class of words distinguished according to the kind of idea denoted and the function performed in a sentence ... but the broader one (eg **Wikipedia**:) In grammar, a part of speech (also a word class, a lexical class, or a lexical category) is a linguistic category of words (or more precisely lexical items), ... **Wiktionary** lexical item  A term—word or a sequence of words—that acts as a unit of meaning, including words, phrases, phrasal verbs and proverbs ...